# Error: Invalid hook call error, Even though I did reset to previous commit

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have been using REACT for a while now and I can properly use hooks and am not breaking any hook rules here. for some reason, I performed npm install to reinstall all packages and after that, I'm getting this error.

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

I also did reset to the previous commit to discard all changes but the error still remains.

this is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "mdbreact": "^5.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uninstall-all-modules": "^1.0.5",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm run build:css && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:css": "postcss src/assets/tailwind.css -o src/assets/main.css",
    "watch:css": "postcss src/assets/tailwind.css -o src/assets/main.css"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.4",
    "postcss": "^8.2.6",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

All packages are up to date and we're working on this particular commit

**None of the other answers to similar errors seem to fix my issue and the worst thing is I am not even able to figure out where the root of the error is. If other info is required pls mention it in the comments.**

Comment: Please run `npm list --depth=0` and compare the installed versions of `react` and `react-dom`. They have to match.

Comment: @trixn yes they match

Answer (score 0):

This issue doesn't always have to be related to the usage of hooks or any other react errors.
This time it was occurring because of a module that I was using "mdbreact". For some reason, their website is down and if your project uses it, you'll end up getting this error.